# Magento 2 Varnish & Cookies

Tags: magento2, cookie, varnish

I have noticed when browsing our website with cache and cookies clear we get Varnish Cache HITS on every page (with cache warm). Once you add an item to cart then browse back to the same pages we get a Varnish cache MISS.

Is this to do with cookies being created once an item is added to cart? then Varnish treating the page as a new cache instance due to the cookie.

Is there a resolve for this or is this standard practice for Magento?

We are using Magento 2.3.3 with Varnish 6. Using the standard Magento VCL our cookies look like the below

[image]